# Sending a Session Variable In a Form

Tags: php, forms, variables

I'm looking to send my session variable: $_SESSION['steamid']
to another webpage by using a form. I also want to have a disabled text form with the variable in it.

Currently, this is the code I have:

```
$variable = $_SESSION['steamid'];
```

and

```
  <input type="hidden" name="b64id" value="'$variable'"/></br>
    <p>Your 64 ID: <input type="text" name="b64id" value="'$variable'" disabled="disabled"/></br>
```

But I am just recieving "$variable" on the other end. I would like to avoid using POST and Cookies but if it's needed I'm happy to use it. I can ensure that $variable has a value.

Comment: Remove single quotes: `"$variable"`

Comment: lower part is html and you defined variable in php. so you cant use that variable unless you make sure it is inside <?php ?>

Answer (score 3):

Two issues:

1. You forgot your PHP tags and echo statement
2. The single quotes are unnecessary if even if you did #1 would cause the same issue to occur

This should do what you need (assuming PHP 5.4+ or short tags enabled):

```
 <p>Your 64 ID: <input type="text" name="b64id" value="<?= $variable ?>" disabled="disabled"/></br>
```

Answer (score 0):

when you want to use PHP variable you should open PHP tag

**NOT CORRECT**

```
<input type="hidden" name="b64id" value="'$variable'"/></br>
    <p>Your 64 ID: <input type="text" name="b64id" value="'$variable'" disabled="disabled"/></br>
```

**CORRECT**

```
<input type="hidden" name="b64id" value="<?php echo $variable ?>"/></br>
    <p>Your 64 ID: <input type="text" name="b64id" value="<?php echo $variable ?>" disabled="disabled"/></br>
```

there is a short form `<?= $variable ?>` 
it means `<?php echo $variable ?>`

WELCOME ON PHP WORD !!!

Enjoy :)

Comment: I'm writing this in $html = and it's still only just echoing $variable

Comment: what is a extention of the file ? html or php ?

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/   use this site to execute your code if you get same result let me know

Comment: For the most part, I really just want to send $_SESSION['steamid'] to another page. Where I can upload it to a mysql database.

Comment: it is a new question ... mark my answer as correct and create new question :)

Answer (score -1):

Use following code having php tags:

```
<input type="hidden" name="b64id" value="<?php echo $variable ?>"/></br>
    <p>Your 64 ID: 
    <input type="text" name="b64id" value="<?php echo $variable ?>" disabled="disabled"/>     
</br>
```

You should also check if `session` having value or not.
like:

```
$variable = (isset($_SESSION['steamid']))?$_SESSION['steamid']):'';
```